# How to make a form on the homepage redirect back instead of to it's own view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails and still learning my way around it, I have a form and I only want the user to be able to access the home page. When you press the save button, it redirects to the view page `memos` when I want it to redirect back to the homepage.

I tried something like this:

```
def create
    @memo = current_user.memos.build(memo_params)

      if @memo.save
        flash[:success] = "Memo created!"
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        @feed_items = []
        flash.keep[:notice] = "no."
        render 'new'
      end
  end
```

My form looks like this, although I don't think it's anything here.

```
<%= form_for(@memo) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :info, placeholder: "Title" %>
  </div> 
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :link, placeholder: "Paste link" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "save", class: "memo-post-button" %>
<% end %>
```

I can't figure out what it is that isn't redirecting back to the homepage. I'm getting the error message on the `memos` page, but I want those to display on the homepage.

Comment: `I'm getting the error message on the memos page, but I want those to display on the homepage.` - so you want to redirect to home even if the memo has not been created?

Comment: Yes, I want to redirect in both situations and keep the error message.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the line

```
render "new"
```

which is what is telling rails to show the memo form again if there was an error.

You will need to have the `redirect_to` under the else as well.  Or move the redirect outside of the if-else altogether

Answer (score 2):

```
if @memo.save
  flash[:success] = "Memo created!"
else
  flash[:notice] = "no."
end
redirect_to root_url
```

UPDATE:

To keep error messages, you could for example do:

```
flash[:notice] = @memo.errors.full_messages.join('. ')
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the error message with this?

Comment: Do you have a place in your layout or view that displays `flash[:notice]`?

Answer (score 0):

Jesse, because you're new let me explain how this works

> Rails is based on the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) - basically meaning
>   you can send the up the application to send data to a *controller*,
>   which will then cause data to be altered in the *model*. The
>   difference here is how to cause Rails to load another view after the controller has done its work

The problem, as stated by many others, is that in order to get rails to load another view, you have to tell it. You've done this by using the `render 'new'` command, which will render the `new` view. You want to redirect to the homepage, which would be achieved by using:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def action
   #other stuff
   redirect_to root_path
end
```